# What does this quote mean; "There's never a lie because there is never a truth"?

Tags: philosophy

Here is the quote by Lenny Bruce in its full context :

> Let me tell you the truth. The truth is "what *is*". If "what is" is,
>   you have to sleep eight, ten hours a day, that is the truth. A lie
>   will be: People need no sleep at all. Truth is "what *is*". If every
>   politician from the beginning was crooked, there is no crooked. But if
>   you are concerned with a lie, "what should be"—and "what should be" is
>   a fantasy, a terrible lie that somone gave the people long ago: This
>   is what *should* be—and no one ever saw what should be, that you don't
>   need any sleep and you can go seven years without sleep, so that all
>   people were made to measure up to that dirty lie. You know there's no
>   crooked politicians. There's never a lie because there's never a
>   truth.

Comment: For your curiosity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certainty

Comment: It should be noted that Bruce was fond of speaking in riddles (and was likely a bit of a nut case).

Answer (score 0):

It means there is no lie, because there is no truth. How can there be **Lie** if there is no **Truth**?

**Lie** is the opposite of **Truth**, so, if there is no *Truth*, consequently, there is no *Lie*.

It's like if you were the first person to be born in the world and "Beauty" hadn't yet been invented, so, how could you be considered to be an Ugly person if the characteristis of beauty hadn't yet been invented?

Like in the **Bible**, before the **Bible** was released, people had been living in sins, but those sins didn't count as sins, because the *bible*, which would explain what *sin* is, hadn't been released yet. Therefore, how could they sin, if the definition of sin hadn't yet been explained?